# CollapsingToolbarLayout not opening and close

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-xml, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to implement CollapsingToolbarLayout just like follows:

[image]

But my CollapsingToolbarLayout never opens or collapse. I have referred to this [tutorial](https://material.io/develop/android/components/collapsing-toolbar-layout/). Here is my code:

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF0"
    tools:context=".activities.TasksListActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/tasks_list_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the java code:

```
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        collToolbar = findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        collToolbar.setTitleEnabled(false);
        collToolbar.setTitle("This is title");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height for your AppBarLayout has been set to 60dp. Change it to 120dp or something larger and set the title to the toolbar before setting the toolbar as the supportActionBar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CollapsingToolbar">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="#FF0"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/tasks_list_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In your activity's java file

```
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        collToolbar = findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);

        toolbar.setTitle("This is title");

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Set your `AppBarLayout` height to something larger - 60dp is very close to the standard toolbar height of 56dp.

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp" <-- Change to something larger (i.e. 240dp)
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:elevation="0dp">
```

Comment: It actually solves the issue regarding collapsing but still, the title is fixed on top and not coming down on a scroll.

Comment: Try modifying your `app:expandedTitleGravity="top"` attribute

Comment: I said modify it - change it to `app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom"`, for instance

Comment: but it's already `app:expandedTitleGravity="top"` in `CollapsingToolbarLayout`